# IOS Paypal transfer money between random app user How to verify

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm building an ios app where it is open market place.User can sale and buy product from another user through paypal.My app will not receive any percentage of money.I have uses PayPal iOS SDK 1.0.5 But problem is my understanding with verification. After user pay money to another user through application in mobile, i'm receiving information of that transaction which i need to verify from server to paypal server.My question is how do i verify transaction between random two app user.My application only know their email ids.

If i use old MPL library,by transaction i will receive paykey after successfull transaction,should i need to verify or paypal handle that automatically,receiver user will verify that payment through pay pal.

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

@HoursDeSajib, the PayPal iOS SDK is based on PayPal's new REST APIs. Those APIs (and therefore the SDK) do not currently support sending money from one user to another. They support only sending money from a logged-in user to a single merchant.

While version 1.x of the SDK did provide an unintended loophole to get around this restriction in some cases, this was never an officially supported use of the SDK.

Recent versions of the SDK (2.x) no longer include that loophole. You should not depend on it continuing to work for you, even with the out-of-date version of the SDK that you are currently using.

We do not yet have an estimated date for when user-to-user payments will be supported by the REST APIs. In the meantime, rather than using the PayPal iOS SDK, you will need to use the older MPL library to accomplish this sort of task.